# how do I get install4jc to compile using java 8

Tags: java-8, install4j

Recently upgraded our project to java 8 now when trying to create the installer i get an UnsupportedClassVersionError 52 so I know it's because it's still running java 7 but I haven't been able to find any configuration option to make it use java 8 when compiling

using install4j 5.1.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to upgrade to install4j 6 for Java 8 support.

Comment: OK thanks, downloaded a trial version of 6 and it fixed that error.  On to the next one...

Answer (score 0):

There is a file pointing to the JRE in use by Install4j and you can just change that to point to a Java 8 JRE placement.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\install4j5\.install4j\pref_jre.cfg
```

Change the file to point to the JRE of your choice e.g:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\install4j5\jre
to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre
```

After changing the file I had to input the license information again when starting Install4j and download the bundled JREs again.

During "Shrinking runtime" I received many `[warning] major version should be between 45 and 51 for JDK <= 1.7` but the compilation finishes and creates the installation media.